# web API POST curl returns 'not found anything matching the request URI'

Tags: php, json, curl

i try to access a web api with json encoded and $POST method in php. After a few tries, i get this message:

> Not Found - The server has not found anything matching the request URI
>   .You can get technical details here. Please continue your visit at our
>   home page.

Why? thank you, my code is:

```
 <?php

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    //DADOS DE ACESSO
    $id = "xxx";
    $retailerName = "xxx";

    $key = "xxx";

    //PRODUTO
    //vars of product:fictional data
    $upc = "799366289999";
    $amount = "20.00";

    //URL DE ACESSO
    $function = "requestActivateCode";

    //usado pra criar a canonical
    $resPath = "/v1/activateCode";

    $url = "https://111.222.333.444/v1/";

    $urlCall = $url.$function;

    //HTTP HEADERS
    $date = gmdate("M, d Y H:i:s \G\M\T", time());
    $contentType = "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    $accept = "Accept: application/json";
    $xIncommDateTime = substr(substr_replace(date('c'), substr(round(microtime(), 3), 1, 8), 19, 0), 0, -6) . "Z";

    //authorization
    $type = "application/json; charset=UTF-8";
    $canonical = ($xIncommDateTime) + ($type) + ($resPath);

    $signature = hash_hmac ('sha1', $key, $canonical);
    $idEncoded = base64_encode($id);
    $signatureEncoded = base64_encode($signature);
    $authorization = "Incomm ". $idEncoded .':'. $signatureEncoded;

    $header = array("Date: ".$date, $contentType, $accept, "X-Incomm-DateTime: ".$xIncommDateTime, "Authorization: ".$authorization);


    //PARAMS example
    $params = array("RetailTransactionRequest" =>
        array(
            "code" => "0000002381237220",
            "amount" => $amount,
            "upc" => $upc,
            "transactionID" => "1234",
            "dateTime" => $xIncommDateTime,
            "retailerName" => $retailerName
        )
    );

    $request = json_encode($params);


    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $urlCall);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 1);
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT ,0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request);
    echo curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true); // enable tracking
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    echo $result;

    $headerSent = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT ); // request headers

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($headerSent);
    echo "</pre>";

    if($result === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($result);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
```

In `netstat -l ip` my port 443 is listening, but the host in ping dont. I want to know how to solve the problem, thank you

Comment: Please post details about this API's endpoint specifications.

Comment: Perhaps you should increase the CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT?

Comment: MY endpoint is:
1.3 API Endpoints
The endpoint is determined by the API operation and the environment in which you want to
execute the transaction. For example, if you want to send a “RequestActiveCode” request to the
sandbox endpoint, specify URL in POST:
https://rtg.sandbox.XXX.com/v1/RequestActiveCode
The following are the current endpoints that can be specified:
Production https://rtg.XXX.com/v1/API_operation
Sandbox https://rtg.sandbox.XXX.com/v1/API_operation
The authentication data is passed in the HTTP header, while the associated retailer identifier is
included in the message payload.

Answer (score 0):

If the code is exactly what is shown I don't think that your server's ip address is correct. Instead of using the IP address (111.222.333.444) used in the example, substitute the IP address of your site or the domain name of your site.

```
$url = "https://111.222.333.444/v1/"
```